# How to install cross-compiler on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: ubuntu, cross-compilation

My proc info:

```
 lscpu
Architecture:        x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:          Little Endian
CPU(s):              4
On-line CPU(s) list: 0-3
Thread(s) per core:  1
Core(s) per socket:  4
Socket(s):           1
NUMA node(s):        1
Vendor ID:           GenuineIntel
CPU family:          6
Model:               158
Model name:          Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7400 CPU @ 3.00GHz
Stepping:            9
CPU MHz:             1036.788
CPU max MHz:         3500,0000
CPU min MHz:         800,0000
BogoMIPS:            6000.00
Virtualization:      VT-x
L1d cache:           32K
L1i cache:           32K
L2 cache:            256K
L3 cache:            6144K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):   0-3
```

I tried:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi g++-arm-linux-gnueabi
```

If I go for:

```
arm-linux-gcc
arm-linux-gcc: command not found
```

How to install cross-compiler?

Comment: According to the [filelist](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi/filelist), the compiler executable name is `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

## TLDR

you need to call `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc` not `arm-linux-gcc`.

---

It looks like you've just got the wrong file name.  For reference `apt-file` is a useful tool.

```
sudo apt-get install apt-file
sudo apt-file update
apt-file search -x 'gcc$' | grep 'gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi'
```

This searches any file ending `gcc` in any package with `gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi` in the name.  The result is:

```
gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi: /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc
```

So if you have installed `gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi` you should have a file `/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc`.

Comment: Knowing to search for `arm-linux-gnueabi` means knowing the answer already ;-). `apt-file search -x 'arm-linux.*gcc$'` would be more discoverable.

Comment: True. It was in the OP's question under "I tried..." but as you say, if you don't know, good knowledge of regular expressions is also helpful.

Comment: My point is that the OP didn’t know what command to run, so couldn’t know what to search for in package contents (as opposed to package names).

Comment: I had no prior knowledge of any of this before attempting to find it myself.  The search in my answer is constructed of the package they already installed and `gcc` at the end of the command name - a generalisation of what they were already trying (`arm-linux-gcc`) - It was the first thing I tried..

Comment: I guess I just find it surprising to use `apt-file search` to look for a package name (as you put it, “This searches all packages for a file or package containing `arm-linux-gnueabi`”) when `apt-file search` only searches package contents (which also incidentally finds package names, thanks to `/usr/share/doc/<package>/copyright`).

Comment: `apt-file search` only matches filenames, not packages; compare for example the output of `apt-file list libevdev-dev` and the output of `apt-file search libevdev-dev`. The `Contents` files which `apt-file` uses look like `file path<tabs>package name[, package name[...]]`.

Comment: Yeah I just found that, odd, I could have sworn it used to be different.  I've edited for a version that works for the right reasons :-)

Comment: `dpkg -L gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi` would have been more useful to the OP, I think (possibly piped to `grep '/bin/` if the list is long)

Comment: Can u please tell how can I install gcc x86-64 cross compiler. What is the exact name in `apt install xx` command

Answer (score 10):

As [steeldriver](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/65304/steeldriver) suggests, you already have installed the cross-compiler; the problem is that you’re using the wrong command to invoke it, you need to use the `arm-linux-gnueabi-` prefix in general. So run

```
arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc
```

or

```
arm-linux-gnueabi-g++
```

and it should work fine.

To figure this out yourself, you can use `dpkg -L` to list the contents of the packages you’ve installed:

```
dpkg -L gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi
```